# Attaching random string from an array to a button

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to make a random string from an array in my strings.xml file to appear on a random button in a linear layout.  I inflate the button, choose a random string from my file, and them attach the random string to the button, then repeat for three buttons.  everything works fine, I can see that it is attaching random strings every time, but the problem is that the button displays the name that I would use to refer to the string, not the strings actual value.  For example if I have a string with a name of: string and value of: "Hello World", it just displays "string" as my button text. 
    private void loadButtons() 
    {

```
   LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

   for (int row = 0; row < guessRows; row++) 
   {
         random = new Random();
         Resources res = getResources();

         String[] truthString = res.getStringArray(R.array.truthArray);
         String truth = truthString[random.nextInt(truthString.length)];

         Button newGuessButton = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.guess_button, null);



         newGuessButton.setText(truth);

         buttonLayout.addView(newGuessButton);

   }
```

Comment: What you have tried? Show us some code.

Comment: Show the code! Looks like a resource problem

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're setting the string array correctly? Individual strings in an array shouldn't have name tags, the only name should be the array name. See [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray), and make sure you're declaring it properly.

Comment: oh I see, originally I had a ton of strings, and I thought that by adding them to the array I just had to use the item and the name of the string already made, but where I was entering the name, I needed to enter a new value.